# CakePHP 3 : Association property name clashes with field of same name of table

Tags: cakephp, model-associations, cakephp-3.2

I am using CakePHP 3.2. I have two tables `service_requests` and `coupon_history`

`service_requests` table

```
CREATE TABLE `service_requests` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `request_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `user_address_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `service_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `service_area_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_used` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0: Not Applied; 1: Applied',
  `coupon_used_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `status_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
)
```

`coupon_history` table

```
CREATE TABLE `coupon_history` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `coupon_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `service_request_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
)
```

When I bake `service_requests` table by

```
bin/cake bake all service_requests
```

It Warning Error as

```
Association property name "coupon_used" clashes with field of same name of table "service_requests". You should explicitly specify the "propertyName" option. in [/var/www/html/flitfix/admin2/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Association.php, line 445]

2016-07-01 07:17:32 Warning: Warning (512): Association property name "coupon_used" clashes with field of same name of table "service_requests". You should explicitly specify the "propertyName" option. in [/var/www/html/flitfix/admin2/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Association.php, line 445]
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleError() - CORE/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php, line 146
Cake\ORM\Association::property() - CORE/src/ORM/Association.php, line 445
Bake\Utility\Model\AssociationFilter::filterAssociations() - ROOT/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Utility/Model/AssociationFilter.php, line 94
Bake\Shell\Task\TemplateTask::_filteredAssociations() - ROOT/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/TemplateTask.php, line 465
Bake\Shell\Task\TemplateTask::_loadController() - ROOT/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/TemplateTask.php, line 295
Bake\Shell\Task\TemplateTask::main() - ROOT/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/Task/TemplateTask.php, line 147
Bake\Shell\BakeShell::Bake\Shell\{closure}() - ROOT/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/BakeShell.php, line 252
Cake\Collection\Collection::each() - CORE/src/Collection/CollectionTrait.php, line 51
Bake\Shell\BakeShell::all() - ROOT/vendor/cakephp/bake/src/Shell/BakeShell.php, line 253
Cake\Console\Shell::runCommand() - CORE/src/Console/Shell.php, line 444
Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::_dispatch() - CORE/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 221
Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 181
Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher::run() - CORE/src/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 127
[main] - ROOT/bin/cake.php, line 33
```

Previously there was `coupon_used` table which I renamed to `coupon_history` and deleted all `controller, model and template` named `coupon_used` and trying to bake again `coupon_history` but it gives error.
I tried with a new project created by composer but in that too same error is there.

Comment: Read the error message again, it clearly tells you what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Yes I can fix the problem as given in error message but the question is why this error even if there is no table `coupon_used` which conflict with column with same name in `service_requests`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as warning says, there is conflict beetween field name "coupon_used" with coupon_useds table property, which is coupon_used. this is happen because default rules of CakePHP.

you should change either field name "coupon_used" or coupun_useds table property with another name in service_requests table model.

```
class ServiceRequests extends Table{
   ....
   //assumption if association is belongsTo
   $this->belongsTo('CouponUsed',['propertyName' => 'AnotherCouponUsed']);
   ....
}
```

Comment: Initially there was `coupon_used` field name in `service_requests` and `coupon_used` table. Then I can understand the cause of error. But now, I have deleted `coupon_used` table and baking application from start creating a new project. Event the error is there. How could it get in conflict even if there is no table by same column name

Comment: so we need some clue about your database table list, service_requests controller and table model codes

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below link. Property name to be defined like this.

```
$this->belongsTo('ProductPrices', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_price_id',
    'className'  => 'ProductPrices',
    'propertyName' => 'prod_price'
]);
```

http://www.cloudypoint.com/Tutorials/discussion/cake-framework-solved-cakephp-3-querybuilder-for-associative-data/

Comment: That answer actually points [back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281597/cakephp-3-querybuilder-for-associative-data) to SO.  Probably better to just mention the update in a comment rather than copying answers from other questions.