# cakephp 3 queryBuilder for associative data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

I have 2 tables.

Table 1:

```
product_prices:
id | price |description |pack |display |created |modified |
```

Table 2:

```
payment_infos:
id |payer |pay_date |product_price_id |product_price |
```

In the `payment_infos` model

```
$this->belongsTo('ProductPrices', [
        'foreignKey' => 'product_price_id',
        'className'  => 'ProductPrices',
]);
```

I have this query:

```
$query = $this->find('all', [
        'contain' => ['ProductPrices']
]));
```

When running the above query I get the following error:

```
Warning (512): Association property name "product_price" clashes 
with field of same name of table "payment_infos". 
You should explicitly specify the "propertyName" option.
[CORE\src\ORM\Association.php, line 722]
```

Comment: replace `'className'  => 'ProductPrices'` with  `'joinType' => 'INNER'`. Have you used bake console for generating model? Also, What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**propertyName**: The property name that should be filled with data from the associated table into the source table results. By default this is the underscored & singular name of the association so `product_price` in our example.

As you already have a field name `product_price` in `payment_infos` it generate a conflict, I changed the default property name to a custom name.

```
$this->belongsTo('ProductPrices', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_price_id',
    'className'  => 'ProductPrices',
    'propertyName' => 'prod_price'
]);
```

See [BelongsTo Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongsto-associations)